# Chrome extension HTML Link wont direct to the website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a new extension I'm making, the button makes a drop down popup and in that I have the HTML code

```
 <html>
 <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
 </html>
```

This code should direct to google, shouldn't it? I know that its working because Google comes up on the popup but when I click it it does nothing.

Comment: Won't that mean that you are opening the page in the drop down popup... not the current browser page?

Comment: I guess so yes, it's just for the method I'm using image links work but text links don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use anchor tag with : target="_blank"